# How to store output of Matlab command (like a pipe in UNIX)?

Tags: matlab

I am asking on this community per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269056/where-is-the-ideal-place-to-ask-a-matlab-question). Please let me know if this is incorrect and which community I should use.

I am trying to evaluate an integral in Matlab using:

`int(x^(2)*sin(n*x),x)`

Which will return:

`(2*x*sin(n*x))/n^2 - cos(n*x)*(x^2/n - 2/n^3)`

I then want to evaluate the result of this integral at specific values (similar to a definite integral, but I do not what to have to recompute the integral over and over again if I need to plug in lots of different points). Is there a way to store the result of the integral as a function? I have tried:

`f = @(x) int(x^(2)*sin(n*x), x)`

but then if I want to evaluate `f` at 0, `f(0)` tries to do: `int((0)^(2)*sin(n*0), x)`, where I want it to do: `(2*(0)*sin(n*(0)))/n^2 - cos(n*(0))*((0)^2/n - 2/n^3)`. Essentially, I want Matlab to take the integral and then evaluate at a certain value, without having to copy and paste the result of the `int()` command onto the next line? I would relate this to [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) in Linux, such that I would like to pipe the output of the `int()` call to the next line and evaluate its result at a specific value. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the following:

`f = symfun(int(x^(2)*sin(n*x),x),x);`

Now I can use `f(0)` as I desire. I also found the following if I wanted to switch to numeric calculation:

`fn = matlabFunction(f)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by saving a symbolic version of the solved equation.

```
sums n x

f = sym('int(x^(2)*sin(n*x),x)')
```

f is now a symbolic representation of

```
(2*x*sin(n*x))/n^2 - cos(n*x)*(x^2/n - 2/n^3)
```

use the command pretty(f) to view it cleanly.

To use this equation to get a numeric answer you use the subs() command:

```
subs( f, [x n], [1,5])
```

I don't have matlab available to check my syntax but if this is the capability you are looking for it should be sufficient to get you started.